# Novel with boy space traveler and his alien buddy

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, space-exploration, planets

I read this book probably 5-6 years ago.

The main plot was about a boy who travels through space to individual planets with an alien buddy of his or something like that. I remember that they lived in a small town in the middle of nowhere and that his space travel begins when he sees a light from his porch like a UFO or something.

In the book he visits a planet with deep caves and large spiders, and another where the grass is perfect and if you rip it out it grows right back. He also visits a planet where an alien there gives him the ability to speak every language.

When the book ends you find out he was looking at the light for merely a split second but because he was space traveling he was able to go to so many different places and do so much.